# How to start a console application and prevent it from closing at the end?

Tags: .net, console, processstartinfo

I'm starting a shell script (.cmd) from my .NET application. I'd like the console window to remain open after the script has completed so that I can check for any errors. I'm trying with `cmd.exe /K:my.cmd`, but for some reason that does not work (the script does not get executed). Even a simple "dir" command does not work. Any other ideas?

To demonstrate, this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
    Arguments = "/K:dir",
    ErrorDialog = true,
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = @"C:\"
});
```

Gives me this:

```
C:\>
```

**Added clarification:** My application (the one that starts the script) is a **windows forms** application. Executing the above code opens a new console window (as it should). I want THAT new console window to remain open. Also, I cannot modify the script. It's an automated build script and it HAS to terminate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is the whole problem, but if you run `cmd /K:dir`, nothing is run.  Using a space instead of a colon makes it work for me.

i.e., `cmd /K dir`

---

It's also worth noting that you can test these commands in the run dialog.  In any recent Windows version this can be done by holding down <kbd>Win</kbd> and pressing <kbd>R</kbd>.

Comment: That's what you get when trying to use the command line of one program after having studied the command line of another program right before that (TortoiseSVN in my case). :P

Answer (score 1):

You could place your commands in a batch (.bat) file, and make the last command within the batch file "pause" (without quotes).  Then, instead of executing cmd, execute the batch file instead.

Sample batch file - test.bat

dir
pause

You could also output the results to a text file, then show the text file within your application.

```
DIR >results.txt
```

Comment: Plausible, but there are many such scripts and I don't want to write a separate .BAT file for each of them. I _could_ generate a temporary .BAT file on the fly... but that seems like a hacky workaround. Isn't there a better way?

Comment: You could output the results to a file, then open and display the file. C:> DIR > dirResults.txt

Answer (score 1):

Remove the colon from your example:

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo()
{
  Arguments = "/K dir",
  ErrorDialog = true,
  FileName = "cmd.exe",
  WorkingDirectory = @"C:\"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I would log errors to a file rather than keep the window open.
to keep the .net console window open add

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

to the end, this will require the user to press Enter to continue. you can also use `Console.ReadKey()` to use any key

if you want to keep the Process windows open the command is `pause`